# JNI build with MinGW

Tags: gcc, java-native-interface, mingw

I have a problem with building a dll with gcc (mingw).
From this site I read how to do it : http://www.mingw.org/node/41

and the problem is that the file jni.h cannot be found unless it is in current folder where is 
the java file, the header c file and c file.
So my question is how to compile the source file *.c with gcc and to include the path to the file jni.h and jni_md.h with no error occurred?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use -I switch to locate jni.h file. For more information read [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html)

Comment: Like this : gcc -Wall -D_JNI_IMPLEMENTATION_ -Wl,--kill-at  -I:"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\include" -I:"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\include\win32"  -shared HelloWorld.c -o HelloWorld.dll ?